# How to Switch Cloth Object Ready for Sewing Simulation into Printable Template

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm making sewing patterns in blender, i.e. several pieces of flat fabric. Typically I create each piece as part of the same mesh object, and join them with edges so that the cloth simulator will sew them together on an avatar.

What I want is to have a linked copy of a sewing pattern, but this time with all pieces laying flat on a surface for rendering. I can't do this directly because laying the pieces out flat would change the mesh object around the avatar, so it wouldn't be positioned properly for draping.

The solution I'm looking for is to have each piece of fabric be a separate mesh object, and using separate sewing spring edge objects to cause each fabric object to sew together with the others like normal. But I don't see how to do it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing what you want to do—can you show an illustration of how you want this to go?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0_8STR_7SOccUdSRy1IRGtnaFk

On the left the garment is a single mesh object, set up to be sewn around the model using cloth simulation. On the left the same garment, also a single mesh object, is set up to be rendered and printed on paper, in order to sew into real cloth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anyway to do what you want. Your best bet is to make an extra copy of the patterns.  You'll have two copies--one for the simulation and one to render as flat patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Simple shape-key should cover your needs.

**Shape keys**

- set up your model as needed
- under "Object Data Properties" create shape key "Basic" and "Key 1"
- rotate parts to flat them into "print" position (with "Key 1" selected)
- for simulation keep "Value" of "Key 1" = 0, for flat (print) version set "Value" = 1

[image]

[image]

More about [Shape Keys](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/shape_keys_panel.html) see Blender Manual